# i want to download or at least view all api.ai system entities

Tags: nlp, artificial-intelligence, bots, api-ai

i want to download or atleast view all api.ai system entities

the purpose is to understand how they made entity like sys.number and sys.date

the problem i'm facing is that i'm using sys.date entity for my bot whihc works very fine for casual cases like "today" "tomorrow" detected as current date

but fails in special cases like: i want to add one more thing that when user say "aaj", "foran" or "abhi" so it also detect as current date, these are slang words for "today" used in a specific region

Comment: When you say "download or atleast view all api.ai system entities" do you mean a reference documentation or the actual implementation?

Comment: all i meant to solve my problem i defined in the question

Comment: @Silvano actual implementation by the way, or may be i want to see both each and every thing

Answer (score 0):

All API.AI system entities are listed here: https://api.ai/docs/reference/system-entities The values of those entities (which seems to be what you're asking for) are too large to be published (i.e. all cities).

If you wish to add additional entity values I'd recommend creating additional entities (like `today` or `tomorrow`) with the values you believe should be included (like `aaj`, `foran` or `abhi`) and handle them either in your webhook or with custom responses specifically using those entities in your response in API.AI.

If you haven't already you may want to check if API.AI supports the language you're trying to implement.  You can check the language of your agent in your API.AI agent's settings (if is not the right language you can select the language you want when creating a new API.AI agent, a list of support languages is here: https://api.ai/docs/reference/language)

Comment: thanks for the response, how can i make additional entity and merge them to the system one, i think i didn't get the point.
my api.ai agent is in English, my target auditions are well educated they understand English and most of them speak English
now i want to target one other class who are also educated but never speak english in their daily life(here some psychology involve) but still they understand english

Comment: so i want to add little support of slang language, just like if they are booking hotel and during slot filling bot will ask them to tell check-in date, they can reply "today", "tomorrow", "after two day" , "january 1st". sys.date support all these and give me date in iso formate on webhook, 
i just want to add some more things as i mentioned in question "aaj"(aaj means today), "abhi"(abhi means now), "kal"(kal means tommorow), "do din baad"(do din baad means after two day) while the exiting "today", "tomorrow", "after two day" , "january 1st" should remain unchange

Comment: the language `Urdu - Pakistan` which is not supported up till now, let me know if there any plan to support them in near future, and also let me know if there is any page or portal in which api.ai discuss its future plans if yes, it will be really really helpful for me to take decisions accordingly

Comment: one more problem is here with the people of Pakistan and India, that when ever they write Urdu, they donot write it in urdu, they write urdu in english and that writing is called `sms urdu` and google keyboard call it `Hinglish`

e.g: if they want to ask someone "how are you" urdu they should write "کیا حال ہے"  but they donot write it like this, instead they write "kya haal hai" this is a big problem, let me know if api.ai is planning to support "Hinglish"?